# Angular2 list and @hostlistener

Tags: html, angular

our application requires to navigate in an html ul li based dropdown in angular 2. i have used below to capture the keys pressed, but problem is that this listener only captures the first key pressed and ignores the subsequent ones.

```
@HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
onKeyPressHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    alert(event.key);
    this.text = this.text.concat(event.key);
    alert(this.text);  // *alerts only the first entered key.*
}
```

Please can you let know what needs to be done for capturing all the keys pressed by the user.

Comment: if this.text is a Array, you must be declare     'text:string[]', if is a string is     this.text=this.text+event.key

Comment: Hi Eliseo, this.text is a string and  this.text=this.text+event.key throws error hence i used concat which works, but how do i capture all the keys pressed ?

Comment: Use console.log(event.key) and console.log(this.text) and see in a console navigator F12- not alert() I suspect that this alert is interference

Comment: Thank you, Eliseo, i could see all keys pressed in console using console.log. i will need to tweak a little but above helps.